# Tumblr default like button does not render a "like"

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, tumblr

So I've been trying to add custom like and reblog buttons using tutorials on stackoverflow to my blog: https://shahbazthemes.tumblr.com The reblog button works fine but the like button won't do anything. So I added default tumblr like/reblog buttons (not included in the theme originally), and again the reblog button works but the like button does not.

I don't have extensive knowledge of the coding but here's what I did:

Added this piece of code to the bottom of every "pic" div. "pic" div here is the div which renders individual posts, so every post has this div.
Here's the piece of code:

```
 <div class="postfooter">
    <li>{LikeButton}</li>
    <li>{ReblogButton}</li>
    </div>
</div>
```

and added a bit of css to make the two **li** elements inline.

Here is my theme code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//en" "https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


   <link href="https://static.tumblr.com/fk8bn8w/QLRq4gbp9/style-my-tooltips.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.tumblr.com/7qjmkr5/IUmmdsy41/jquery.style-my-tooltips.js"></script><script>(function($){$(document).ready(function(){$("[title]").style_my_tooltips();});})(jQuery);</script>

   <title>{Title}</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">
{block:Description}
<meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />
{/block:Description}


<meta name="color:scrollbar" content="#cdf6ce">
<meta name="color:scrollbar bg" content="white">
<meta name="color:bg" content="#f9f9f9">
<meta name="color:body" content="black">
<meta name="color:bold" content="black">
<meta name="color:links" content="gray">
<meta name="color:post bg" content="white">
<meta name="color:borders" content="#e5e4e2">
<meta name="color:title" content="black">
<meta name="color:Navigation Links" content="black">
<meta name="color:description" content="black">
<meta name="color:perma box3" content="#cdf6ce">
<meta name="color:blockquote bg" content="#e8e8e8">

<meta name="color:Like Reblog color" content="#333333">
<meta name="color:Like Reblog Hover color" content="#00bceb">

<meta name="if:200px" content="0">
<meta name="if:250px" content="0">
<meta name="if:300px" content="1">
<meta name="if:400px" content="0">
<meta name="if:caption" content="0">

<meta name="image:bg image" content="" />
<meta name="image:side image" content="https://41.media.tumblr.com/cf93988618035cbb39c35c402a1ddbdd/tumblr_nigsu3SqL21rlma8ao5_1280.jpg" />

<meta name="text:link one" content="archive">
<meta name="text:link one url" content="/archive">
<meta name="text:link two">
<meta name="text:link two url">
<meta name="text:link three">
<meta name="text:link three url">


<style type="text/css">

{customcss}

.postfooter li{
 list-style:none;
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
  z-index:99999999 !important;
  padding:5px !important;
}
.postfooter{
  height:80px;width:100%
}

a{
        cursor:pointer !important;
}
/*CUSTOM CSS*/
.pic:hover .wh,#red,#velvet{
    display:none !Important;
}
#a a{
    color:{color:Navigation Links};
}

blockquote{
  max-width:300px !important
}
.pic{
  min-width:400px !important;
}

blockquote img{
  max-width:350px !important;
  height:auto !important
}
/*CUSTOM CSS*/

.tumblr_blog{
    color:{color:Author name color} !important;
}


/*important stuff*/
#s-m-t-tooltip{
    max-width:400px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:20px;
    padding: 2px;
    z-index:9999999999;
    background-color:white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color:black;
    font-family:roboto;
    font-size:9px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #e8e8e8;
        -moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #e8e8e8;
        -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #e8e8e8;

}

iframe#tumblr_controls {
    top:0%!important;
    right:0%!important;
    position:fixed!important;
    z-index:9999999999!important;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-filter:invert(100%);
    -moz-filter:invert(100%);
    -o-filter:invert(100%);
    -ms-filter:invert(100%);
    filter:invert(100%);
}


/*scrollll*/
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    background-color:{color:scrollbar};
    height:40px;  
    z-index:9999;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color:{color:scrollbar bg};
    height:5px;
    width:5px;
    z-index:9999;
}
/*posts*/
#content{
    width:400px;
    padding:30px;
    margin-left:40%;


    {block:permalinkpage}width:450px;

    {/block:permalinkpage}
}

.pic{
    margin:20px;
    float:left;
     padding:20px;

  background-color:{color:post bg};
  border:1px dotted {color:borders};
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:10px;
    {block:indexpage}
   {block:if300px} width:300px;{/block:if300px}
   {block:if200px} width:200px;{/block:if200px}
   {block:if250px}width:250px;{/block:if250px}
   {block:if400px}width:400px;{/block:if400px}
   margin-top:30px;


    {/block:indexpage}
    {block:permalinkpage}
    width:400px;

    {/block:permalinkpage}
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}


blockquote {
    width:100%;
    margin-left:15px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-top:1px;
    padding-bottom:1px;
background-color:{color:blockquote bg};
    }

a{color:{color:links}; text-decoration:none;

    }
a:hover {background-color:{color:links hover};

}
ul, ol{}
ul.chat {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;}

.chat li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 2px;}
.chat{ padding:15px;}
.quote { font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-family:roboto;font-style:none;}
#not ol li {
list-style-type:none;  
}
#not{height:100px;
width:430px;
overflow:auto;}

#ans img{{block:if300px}max-width:290px;{/block:if300px}
{block:if200px}max-width:190px;{/block:if200px}
{block:if250px}max-width:240px;{/block:if250px}
{block:if400px}max-width:390px;{/block:if400px}
overflow:hidden;}
#ans {word-wrap:break-word;}

i, em{font-weight: light;}
b, strong{font-weight:bold; color:{color:bold};}
*, body  {cursor:default;}
a, a:hover {cursor:help;}
h3{ font-weight:normal;
text-align:center;}
#text img{
   {block:indexpage} {block:if300px}max-width:290px;{/block:if300px}
{block:if250px}max-width:240px;{/block:if250px}
{block:if200px}max-width:190px;{/block:if200px}
{block:if400px}max-width:390px;{/block:if400px}{/block:indexpage}
   {block:permalinkpage}max-width:390px;{/block:permalinkpage}
    overflow:hidden;
}
#text{word-wrap:break-word;
}
#perma{width:450px;
    text-align:center;
}
/*stuff*/
body {font-size: 12px;
        font-family:roboto;
        color:{color:body};
        word-wrap:break-word;
        background-color:{color:bg};
        background-image:url('{image:bg image}');
        background-size:100% 100%;
        background-attachment:fixed;

}
#ques{border-bottom:{color:borders} 1px dotted;background-color:{color:post bg};padding-bottom:5px;}
#ques a{color:{color:body}; text-decoration:underline; font-style:italic;}
.pagination{display:none;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:Center;
    position:fixed;
left:100px;
    font-family:roboto;
    color:{color:body};
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.pagination a{color:{color:body};
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.pagination a:hover{text-decoration:none;}

.ps {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.video{{block:indexpage}{block:if200px}width:200px;{/block:if200px}{block:if300px}width:300px;{/block:if300px}{block:if250px}width:250px;{/block:if250px}{block:if400px}width:400px;{/block:if400px} overflow:hidden;{/block:indexpage}}
#audio *{
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    padding-left:2.5px;
    margin-top:-41px;
    opacity:0.7;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#audio:hover *{opacity:0.8;-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;}
#audioinfo{padding-left:80px;
    margin-top:-90px;
}

{block:ifcaption}#cap{
font-family:roboto;
padding:2px;
margin-top:3px;
font-size:10px;
text-align:left;
}{/block:ifcaption}
{block:ifnotcaption}#cap{display:none;}{/block:ifnotcaption}

#red{position:absolute;
width:0px;
height:1px;
    background-color:{color:borders};
    {block:if200px}margin-left:236px;{/block:if200px}
   {block:if300px} margin-left:336px;{/block:if300px}
   {block:if250px}margin-left:286px;{/block:if250px}
   {block:if400px}margin-left:436px;{/block:if400px}
    margin-top:9px;
}
#velvet{position:absolute;
    width:1px;
    height:0px;
    background-color:{color:borders};
    {block:if200px}margin-left:227px;{/block:if200px}
 {block:if300px} margin-left:327px;{/block:if300px}
   {block:if250px}margin-left:277px;{/block:if250px}
   {block:if400px}margin-left:427px;{/block:if400px}
    margin-top:13px;}
.wh{width:15px;
    height:15px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:0px;
    {block:if200px}margin-left:220px;{/block:if200px}
    {block:if300px}margin-left:320px;{/block:if300px}
    {block:if250px}margin-left:270px;{/block:if250px}
    {block:if400px}margin-left:420px;{/block:if400px}
    border:1px solid {color:borders};
    border-radius:5%;
    background-color:{color:perma box1};
    opacity:0;
       -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.pic:hover #red{opacity:1;width:28px;
}
.pic:hover #velvet{opacity:1;height:31px;}
.pic:hover #box{opacity:1;margin-left:43px;}
.pic:hover #box2{opacity:1;margin-top:30px;}
.pic:hover .wh{opacity:1;}
.wh:hover{opacity:1;}

#box,#box2{width:10px;
height:10px;
border:1px solid {color:borders};
border-radius:5%;
opacity:0;
}
#box{background-color:{color:perma box2};
    margin-left:23px;
    margin-top:1.5px;
}
#box2{background-color:{color:perma box3};
margin-top:20px;}


.side{position:fixed;
top:30%;
left:30%;
border:1px dotted {color:borders};
border-radius:5%;
 background-color:white;


}
#pc{
border-radius:5%;
width:100px;
height:100px;
margin:10px;
overflow:hidden;
background-position:center;
background-size:cover;
background-image:url('{image:side image}');
}
#dc{position:absolute;
right:100%;
top:45%;
    height:1px;
    background-color:{color:borders};
}
#ac{position:absolute;
width:1px;
left:50%;
top:100%;
}
#a{position:relative;
width:100px;
text-align:right;
margin-left:-105px;
margin-top:10px;
font-family:roboto;
}
#b{position:relative;
    font-style:italic;
    color:{color:description};
    width:150px;
    font-size:11px;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-top:5px;
    font-family:roboto;
}
#bc{position:absolute;
bottom:133px;
color:{color:title};
    background-color:white;
    border:1px dotted {color:borders};
    width:100px;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:5px;
    opacity:1;
}
</style>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
{block:IndexPage}<script src="https://static.tumblr.com/wgijwsy/u2vm2hxv6/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $container = $('#content');
        $container.infinitescroll({
            itemSelector: '.pic',
            navSelector: '.pagination',
            nextSelector: '.next',
            loadingImg: '',
            loadingText: '<em></em>',
            bufferPx: 2000

        });

});
</script>
{/block:IndexPage}
</head>
<body>
<div class="side">
    <div id="bc">{title}</div>
    <div id="ac">
        <div id="a"><a href="/">home</a>
            <br><a href="/ask">message</a>
           {block:iflinkone} <br><a href="{text:link one url}">{text:link one}</a>{/block:iflinkone}
           {block:iflinktwo} <br><a href="{text:link two url}">{text:link two}</a>{/block:iflinktwo}
         {block:iflinkthree}   <br><a href="{text:link three url}">{text:link three}</a>{/block:iflinkthree}
        </div></div>
    <div id="dc">
        <div id="b">{description}</div>
    </div>
   <div id="pc" {block:ifsidebareffect}title="{title}"{/block:ifsidebareffect}></div>
</div>

<div class="pagination">
{block:Pagination}{block:PreviousPage}<a href="{PreviousPage}"><<</a> {/block:PreviousPage}  {block:NextPage}<a  href="{NextPage}" class="next" >>></a>{/block:NextPage}{/block:Pagination}</div>





<div id="content">

{block:Posts}
<div class="entry">

    {block:Text}
    <div class="pic">


    {block:Title}<h3 id="title" style="text-align:left; font-size:25px;" >{Title}</h3>{/block:Title}

           <div id="text"> {Body}</div> 
     <div class="postfooter">
        <li>{LikeButton}</li>
        <li>{ReblogButton}</li>
        </div>
    </div>  



   {/block:Text}

    {block:Photo}
    <div class="pic">



     <center>
        {block:IndexPage}

      <a href="{permalink}">  <img src="{PhotoURL-400}" width="{block:if300px}300px;{/block:if300px}{block:if250px}250px;{/block:if250px}{block:if200px}200px;{/block:if200px}{block:if400px}400px;{/block:if400px}" ></a>
        <div id="cap">{block:Caption}
        {Caption}
        {/block:Caption}</div>



        {/block:IndexPage}

        {block:PermalinkPage}
        <a href="{LinkURL}">
        <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}">

        {/block:PermalinkPage}

        </a>
        </center>
        {block:PermalinkPage}
        {block:Caption}
        {Caption}
        {/block:Caption}
        {/block:PermalinkPage}
        <div class="postfooter">
        <li>{LikeButton}</li>
        <li>{ReblogButton}</li>
        </div>

    </div> 
    {/block:Photo}

     {block:Photoset}
    <div class="pic">


     {block:IndexPage}

     <div class="ps">

{Photoset}
</div>
 <div id="cap">{block:Caption}
        {Caption}
        {/block:Caption}</div>


    {/block:IndexPage}

    {block:PermalinkPage}
        {Photoset-400}
        {block:Caption}
        {Caption}
        {/block:Caption}
    {/block:PermalinkPage}
         <div class="postfooter">
        <li>{LikeButton}</li>
        <li>{ReblogButton}</li>
        </div>
</div>
    {/block:Photoset}

   {block:Quote}
    <div class="pic">

    <div class="quote">{Quote}

        {block:Source}
<div style="text-align:right; line-height:25px; font-size:12px;"class="source">  {Source}</div>


{/block:Source}</div>






    </div>
    {/block:Quote}

    {block:Link}
    <div class="pic">


    <h3><a href="{URL}" {Target}>{Name}</a></h3>


   </div>

   {/block:Link}

    {block:Chat}
    <div class="pic">

    {block:Title}
<h3>{Title}</h3>
{/block:Title}
<ul class="chat">
{block:Lines}
<li class="{Alt} user_{UserNumber}">
{block:Label}
<span class="label"><b>{Label}</b></span>
{/block:Label}
{Line}
</li>
{/block:Lines}
</ul>

   </div>
   {/block:Chat}

    {block:Audio}
    <div class="pic">

     {block:AlbumArt}
<img style="width:70px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px" src="{AlbumArtURL}">
{/block:AlbumArt}

<div id="audio">

{block:AudioPlayer} {AudioPlayerwhite} {/block:AudioPlayer}                       
</div><div id="audioinfo">Track: {block:TrackName}{TrackName}{/block:TrackName}<br>Artist: {block:Artist}{Artist}{/block:Artist}<br>
        {block:PlayCount}{PlayCountWithLabel}{/block:PlayCount}</div>
{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
{/block:Permalinkpage}


    </div>
    {/block:Audio}

    {block:Video}
    <div class="pic">

     <div class="video">
  {block:IndexPage}

    {Video-400} 
   {/block:IndexPage} 

 {block:PermalinkPage}
        {Video-400}
        {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
        {/block:PermalinkPage}

     </div>

    </div>
    {/block:Video}

    {block:Answer}
    <div class="pic">


<div id="ques">{Asker} whispered: <i>{Question}</i></div><div id="ans">{Answer}</div>
 <div class="postfooter">
        <li>{LikeButton}</li>
        <li>{ReblogButton}</li>
        </div>
    </div>
{/block:Answer}

{block:PermalinkPage}
    <div id="perma">
        <center>{block:NoteCount}{NoteCountWithLabel} <img src="https://media.tumblr.com/00a827740e10acc5ac5985d0270b8735/tumblr_inline_n2aihb9pLr1r7v6wt.png"> {/block:NoteCount}{block:Date}{ShortYear}/{MonthNumberWithZero}/{DayOfMonthWithZero}{/block:Date}{block:RebloggedFrom} <img src="https://media.tumblr.com/00a827740e10acc5ac5985d0270b8735/tumblr_inline_n2aihb9pLr1r7v6wt.png"> <a href="{ReblogParentURL}" title="{ReblogParentName}">via</a> <img src="https://media.tumblr.com/00a827740e10acc5ac5985d0270b8735/tumblr_inline_n2aihb9pLr1r7v6wt.png">  <a href="{ReblogRootURL}" title="{ReblogRootName}">source</a>{/block:RebloggedFrom}<br>{block:HasTags} {block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}">#{Tag}</a> {/block:Tags} {/block:HasTags}
        </center>
    </div>
{block:PostNotes}
    <div id="not">{PostNotes}</div>
{/block:PostNotes}
{/block:PermalinkPage}

</div>
{/block:Posts}


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me sort it out. If you can, please run it in any demo blog.

Thanks.

Comment: UPDATE: This only seems to be an issue with Google Chrome. it works in Firefox.

Comment: `<li>` elements belong inside either a `<ul>` or `<ol>` (unordered list or ordered list). It might be that the browser is interpreting the code, but you should update the markup.